# How can I made a collision mask?

Tags: python, pygame

I try to make a collision mask to detect if two sprites collide themselves, but It's not working at all, I got an instant crash, Can you help me ?

My code is :

```
        Player.rect = Player.image.get_rect()
        oc1.rect = oc1.image.get_rect()
        mask_1 = pg.mask.from_surface(Player)
        mask_2 = pg.mask.from_surface(oc1)
        Cm = pg.sprite.collide_mask(mask_1, mask_2)
        if Cm != None :
            print('life - 1')
```

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation of [`pygame.sprite.collide_mask()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask):

> Collision detection between two sprites, using masks.
>
> ```
> collide_mask(SpriteLeft, SpriteRight) -> point
> ```
>
> **Tests for collision between two sprites**, by testing if their bitmasks overlap. If the sprites have a "mask" attribute, that is used as the mask, otherwise a mask is created from the sprite image. Intended to be passed as a collided callback function to the *collide functions. Sprites must have a "rect" and an optional "mask" attribute.

The parameters to `.collide_mask()` have to be 2 [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects, rather than 2 mask [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) objects:

In the following is assumed, that `Player` and `oc1` are [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects:

```py
Player.rect = Player.image.get_rect()
oc1.rect = oc1.image.get_rect()

Cm = pg.sprite.collide_mask(Player, oc1)

if Cm != None :
    print('life - 1')
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteMask](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SpriteMask#main.py)</kbd>

See also [Sprite mask](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_sprite_and_sprite_mask.md#sprite-mask)