# rotating player around center works but collisions with walls don't anymore

Tags: python, pygame

I can rotate the player around its center position smoothly. However when I reach wall and rotate diagonally, the player teleports to another location on the map. I believe this is due to my player rect being larger when it rotates but I am not sure how to fix it. Here is the relevant code in my player class:

EDIT: I have now fixed the wall collision by creating a rectangle (self.hitbox_rect) that surrounds the original player image, and thus stays the same size whilst rotating. My collision code checks if the player collides with this smaller rectangle. However, I now have an issue which is: my camera keeps shaking when i am close to a wall and rotating. I have updated my code and also added some info about the camera class - maybe it is relevant?

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.player_img = pygame.image.load("handgun/move/survivor-move_handgun_0.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.player_img
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, 0, 0.35)
        self.original_image = self.image  
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)

        self.player_speed = 10 # was 4
        self.shoot = False
        self.shoot_cooldown = 0
        self.bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)
        self.pos = pos

        self.hitbox_rect = self.original_image.get_rect(center = pos)

 
    def player_turning(self): 
        self.mouse_coords = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 

        self.x_change_mouse_player = (self.mouse_coords[0] - (WIDTH // 2))
        self.y_change_mouse_player = (self.mouse_coords[1] - (HEIGHT // 2))
        self.angle = int(math.degrees(math.atan2(self.y_change_mouse_player, self.x_change_mouse_player)))
        self.angle = (self.angle + 360) % 360

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, -self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


    def check_collision(self, direction): 
        for sprite in obstacles_group:
            if sprite.rect.colliderect(self.hitbox_rect):
                if direction == "horizontal":
                    if self.velocity_x > 0:
                        self.rect.right = sprite.rect.left
                        self.hitbox_rect.right = sprite.rect.left 
                    if self.velocity_x < 0:
                        self.rect.left = sprite.rect.right
                        self.hitbox_rect.left = sprite.rect.right
                
                if direction == "vertical":
                    if self.velocity_y < 0:
                        self.rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
                        self.hitbox_rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
                    if self.velocity_y > 0:
                        self.rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top
                        self.hitbox_rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top

    def move(self):
        self.rect.centerx += self.velocity_x
        self.hitbox_rect.x += self.velocity_x
        self.check_collision("horizontal")
        self.rect.centery += self.velocity_y
        self.hitbox_rect.y += self.velocity_y
        self.check_collision("vertical")
```

```
class Camera(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.offset = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.floor_rect = background.get_rect(topleft = (0,0))

        self.create_map()

    def custom_draw(self):
        self.offset.x = player.rect.centerx - (WIDTH // 2)
        self.offset.y = player.rect.centery - (HEIGHT // 2)

        #draw the floor
        floor_offset_pos = self.floor_rect.topleft - self.offset
        screen.blit(background, floor_offset_pos)

        for sprite in all_sprites_group:
            offset_pos = sprite.rect.topleft - self.offset
            screen.blit(sprite.image, offset_pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you place an object near a wall and rotate it, it may intersect with the wall:

[image]

There are many different ways to solve this problem. One option would be that the object may not be rotated if it intersects with the wall after rotation:

1. rotate object
2. collision test
3. undo rotation when a collision is detected

Another object would be to correct the position of the object after the rotation:

1. rotate object
2. collision test
3. when a collision is detected, the object is shifted to the side so that it no longer collides

---

Note that you might get fewer collisions from rotated objects when using collision detection with mask. See [PyGame collision with masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455811/pygame-collision-with-masks) and
[Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision) and [How can I made a collision mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043600/how-can-i-made-a-collision-mask).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your first suggestion: rotate object -> collision test -> rotation when a collision is detected. Also, will using masks get rid of my collision problem or is that just to make it look smoother

Comment: @juba1029 1. Should be "undo rotation when a collision is detected".  2. "Also, will using masks get rid of my collision problem" - No, not completely, but it can reduce the cases where a rotation causes a collision. It depends on the player sprite . (if the sprite was a circle, you would be rid of the problem).